# Div disappears when typing in non-related textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a strange occurrence. I have a div which is both draggable and resizable. The following coding was used on it:

```
$('#myID').draggable({snap:"#parentDiv"}).resizable();
```

Afterwards I created textboxes to use for the puspose of resizing the width and height of the div like so:

```
<table id='hwStyle'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Width: 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='elementWidth' value='100px' size='4'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Height:  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='elementHeight' value='100px' size='4'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The next step was to add `class selected` to the div when it's selected, but even so, it's still not linked with the textboxes in any way. When the div is selected and you start typing in the textbox, the div disappears.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EepRQ/3/). To test it, open layout panel in panelbar, and drag div onto canvas. Just bear with me, it's alot of coding.
To find this div in the coding, search for an ID that starts with `editor`.

Not everything in the fiddle works as it should, as some of the resources cannot be added.

> Any ideas why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

I see that the textbox's ID's which are: elementWidth and elementHeight, aren't fount in my script and also that `class selected` isn't added in the fiddle when a div is selected, so this won't be seen in the fiddle.

Comment: can u please provide a fiddle?

Comment: I have added the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem here:

```
$(document).keydown (function(e) {
    //alert(e.which);
    if(e.which == 46);      
    {
        var selectedComponent = $("#droptarget").find(".selected").attr('id');
        $("#" + selectedComponent).remove();
    }
});
```

The `;` after the if statement shouldn't be there.